# WriteCharacteristics send data faster twice

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm communicating with a custom external device, and this device requires when I send data, I must send the same data once again, between 10 and 100 milliseconds *(send the data twice 10-100 ms interval)*.

Basically it's working very well to send the data, but the second sending is between 500 - 800 milliseconds, so I must decrease it.

I using `Plugin.BLE`

```cs
...
public async Task WriteCharacteristics(byte value)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] data = {value};
                await Service.GetCharacteristicsAsync().ContinueWith(async task =>
                {
                    Characteristics = task.Result;

                    await Characteristics.First().WriteAsync(data).ContinueWith(async t1 =>
                    {
                        await Characteristics.First().StartUpdatesAsync();
                    });
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("********* Failed to get ReadCharacteristics: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
...
```

and when I call:

```cs
...
 _ = ble.WriteCharacteristics((byte)value).ContinueWith(_ =>
     {
          Thread.Sleep(10);
          ble.WriteCharacteristics((byte)value).Wait();
     });
...
```

I tried to call the function twice, as parallel, but that solution not good.

As you see when I call, it waits 10 milliseconds, and want to send the data again. Is there any workaround to solve this problem?

Comment: hint: best not mix async and threads. use `await Task.Delay(10)` instead of `Thread.Sleep(10)`

Comment: I tried that too, and tried without sleeping, but the second sending always between 500 and 800 ms.

Comment: Why are you using both `await` and `ContinueWith`? And what is the actual failure? Have you timed the methods to check the delay between the two `WriteCharacteristics` calls?

Comment: I tried without continue with too. I timed in the device to check the delay, and in the device I see the writeCharacteristics succeed, but between 500 - 800 msec. So the sending always success, and not fails, but the device which I communicate from mobile necessary to send the same data again with between 10 - 100 milliseconds

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why does the BLE device require to send the data twice? If this is some kind of transmission check it's unnecessary since BLE already checks data for completeness on it's own

Comment: Because the device cpu frequency is very-very low, because its working from AAA battery, and that's because the device can't handle the first data, just sense that something happens in bluetooth, and then the cpu frequency will raise until 10-100 milliseconds, and waiting the bluetooth data, after 100 milliseconds ended, the cpu will entering very low frequency again

Comment: It looks there is something wrong with your device concept. That should never been so that you need to send data twice. May its better to run data advertising on PC side and the device will capture the advertising when needed and get data from it. And no, you can not create such time-dependent application son Windows because Windows is not real time OS.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Its a Xamarin.forms application, not windows. Sadly I can't modify the device logic where I connecting to. So I must figure out a solution in my program, how can I manage that.

Comment: What OS it runs on? I guess Android. It is also not real-time OS except for some critical tasks.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko My mobile application is in Xamarin.Forms, and built to Android and iOS, the device where I must connect is OSLess  the firmware written in Assembly

Comment: You are trying to run task that requires real-time OS (precision timing) on non-real time OS. It will never work. The only way to do that is to write your own Bluetooth driver and use hardware interrupts from Bluetooth hardware. In this case you can do what you need.

Comment: for audio, bluetooth codec latency on some android devices: https://www.soundguys.com/android-bluetooth-latency-22732/ - latencies ranged from 244 ms to 484 ms, depending on the phone. Hopefully its not that bad for non-audio use of bluetooth, as in your case. A google blog claims its much better https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/03/an-update-on-androids-audio-latency.html

Answer (score 1):

One reason for the long delay between write operations could be the writeType.  There are two types, `writeWithResponse` and `writeWithoutResponse`. The first is the safer method because you will receive a confirmation if your message was sent correctly. This obviously restricts data throughput.

Setting the writeType to writeWithoutResponse could work in your case. This [issue](https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le/issues/125#issuecomment-269420962) on github shows the correct way:

```cs
Characteristics.WriteType = Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.CharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse;
```

Comment: Thank you the solution, but sadly the result is the same. Te device receive the datas between 500 and 800 sec

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues that can be improved:

1. As mentioned by JonasH in a comment, don't use `async/await` and `ContinueWith` together. `await` is sufficient to suspend your code until an async Task completes.
2. Re-use the "setup" of the communications, so that only the final call needs to be done twice.

I'm not familiar with that plugin (looked at its docs just now, to confirm the basic approach), so this code may need some adjustment, but hopefully this will be a starting point:

```cs
public async Task WriteByteTwice(byte value)
    {
        try
        {
            // Plug-in docs say WriteAsync call should be on MAIN THREAD.
            if (!Xamarin.Essentials.MainThread.IsMainThread)
                throw new InvalidProgramException("WriteByteTwice must be called from MainThread");

            byte[] data = {value};
            Characteristics = await Service.GetCharacteristicsAsync();
            
            // Send data first time.
            await Characteristics.First().WriteAsync(data);
            await Characteristics.First().StartUpdatesAsync();

            await Task.Delay(10);
            
            // Send data again.
            await Characteristics.First().WriteAsync(data);
            await Characteristics.First().StartUpdatesAsync();
            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("********* Failed to get ReadCharacteristics: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```